# pinescript 5: trigger alert only once

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to set multpiple alerts in my code; but I'd like these alerts to be trigged only once each. Of course, one trigged alert mustn't disable another.
I'll take a simple example: let's say I have alert 1 that triggers if price crosses 1.2, and alert 2 that triggers if price crosses 0.8, so I've written:

```
var trigger_alert_1 = false
var trigger_alert_2 = false

if(  ta.cross( close, 1.2 ) and not trigger_alert_1  )
     alert( "alert 01 triggered",  alert.freq_all )
     trigger_alert_1 := true

if(  ta.cross( close, 0.8 ) and not trigger_alert_2  )
     alert( "alert 02 triggered",  alert.freq_all )
     trigger_alert_2 := true
```

And the alerts don't ring out.
What do I do wrong?